# Identify the primary node in a Java EE cluster

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss

I have a web application that get deployed on a jboss (eap 6.2) domain with 2 nodes.
There are certain startup processes that need to be excecuted, however right now the processes run on both nodes. This is undesirable, I need the process to run only on 1 server (identified as primary).

Obviously this can be done by having a special system property set up 1 of the servers, howeever I am wondering if there is a standard Java EE way of designating a node as primary and then reading that configuration in the code?

Answer (score 0):

There is no defined standard. Some application servers provide HA Singletons (https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/JBMHASingleton for JBoss 4.x and http://www.jboss.org/quickstarts/eap/cluster-ha-singleton/ for JBoss 7/Wildfly 8).

There are some approaches like using JGroups or persisting the state in some sort of database. You could also use a clustered JMS Topic. The first node broadcasts "I'm initializing" and others have to listen to it. That's not the best approach but it's within Java EE bounds.